# Stallings' Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, quotient-group

I am trying to understand Stallings' Theorem for lower central series. Here is the statement:

> Say we have groups $A, B$ with lower central series $A=A_1, A_2, ...$ and $B=B_1, B_2, ...$ respectively. Let $\phi : A \rightarrow B$ be a group homomorphism inducing an isomorphism $H_1(A) \rightarrow H_1(B)$ and an epimorphism $H_2(A) \rightarrow H_2(B)$. Then for all $n=1, 2, ...$, $f$ induces an isomorphism $A/A_n \rightarrow B/B_n$.

Here's the problem: what is meant by $H_i(A)$ and $H_i(B)$? I'm familiar with homology, but my understanding is that one speaks of the homology of a *chain complex*. What is the homology of a group? Is there a chain complex at play here?

Comment: First, it's "Stallings's", because his name was Stallings, not "Stalling". Second, one one expect wherever you found the statement would explain the notation. They are the first and second integral homology groups. Finally, look up "group cohomology" and "group homology" for the definitions.

Comment: This does not help. The homology groups of which chain complex?

Comment: You resolve something like $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ for ordinary homology.

Comment: Look up group homology/cohomology. E.g.,https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology?wprov=sfti1

Comment: Again, I know what homology and cohomology are. But they are typically defined in terms of a chain complex. So I reiterate my question, what is the chain complex in this situation?

Comment: Actually, the Wikipedia page you linked seems to answer my question. Thanks.